# Why I can't seem to modify my window properties when not using default XCode4 code structure?

Tags: cocoa

Well, first of all, I hope I stated my problem correctly.
I am using Xcode4, but not using the default code structure.
I am aiming at creating a transparent window here. Now, it's very easy by just adding initialization code here :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [[self window] setAlphaValue:0.9];
    [[self window] setOpaque: NO]; 
}
```

But, because I change the WindowAppDelegate into this :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
  {
    NSLog(@"delegate: init main window");
    mainWindow = [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
    [[mainWindow window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [[mainWindow window] setAlphaValue:0.8];
    [[mainWindow window] setTitle:@"Fool"];
  }
```

It won't work. I mean the code of setAlphaValue didn't had any effect, nor other method call such as setTitle.

I guess this is because of me didn't wire things correctly in the NIB... 
But, what is it anyway?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you connected the `window` outlet in File’s Owner (which should be of type `MainWindowController`) to the actual window?

Comment: I'll have a look at it @Bavarious! Thanks

Comment: :) you did it @Bavarious (again). I remember you often answer my question. And, would you mind moving your comment to the answer part? so that I can accept your answer this way. It really is a simple task, but sometimes I forgot this! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bavarious. This is his answer "Have you connected the window outlet in File’s Owner (which should be of type MainWindowController) to the actual window? – Bavarious Oct 30 at 7:37"

I will accept in in two days  as the answer for my question.

Thanks @bavarious!